# Pass ArrayList of integer array via bundle

Tags: android, arraylist, bundle

I'm looking for a way to pass, via bundle, an

```
ArrayList<Integer[]>
```

object to a Fragment (after activity is already created, so i can't use intent). By looking to android api, no method seems to do what i'm looking for. How can i do?

Comment: ArrayList of object. Shows us your code

Comment: Sorry, i want to pass an ArrayList of integer array

Comment: i would send using shared preferences and remove them ,when they are no longer needed

Answer (score 2):

Sending activity:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle extraBundle = new Bundle();

extraBundle.putIntegerArrayList("arraylist", [put array list here]);

intent.putExtras(extraBundle);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.myapp", "com.myapp.SecondActivity"));

startActivity(intent);
```

Receiving activity's onCreate():

```
final Intent intent = getIntent();
final Bundle extraBundle = intent.getExtras();

ArrayList<Integer> myIntegerArrayList = extraBundle.getIntegerArrayList("arraylist");
```

You can change `"arraylist"` to what you want in the setter and getter method calls, they just need to be the same.

Comment: Activity is already started, i need to pass that ArrayList to a fragment

Comment: @giozh you need to edit your question with more details and be specific

Answer (score 0):

I used Gson, convert to JSONArray and send via Bundle. But it may affects performance.

In First Activity

```
Intent activity = new Intent(MyActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
activity.putExtra("myArrayList", new Gson().toJson(myArrayList);
startActivity(activity);
```

In other activity..

```
Sting myArrayList;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
   myArrayList= extras.getString("myArrayList");

   Type listOfInteger = new TypeToken<List<Integer>>(){}.getType();
   String s = new Gson().toJson(myArrayList, listOfInteger);
   List<Integer> myList = new Gson().fromJson(s, listOfInteger); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] intarray = new int[] {4,5,6,7,8};

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putIntArray("integerarray", intarray);
```

Or an ArrayList with int arrays?

For that i think you should use [Parcable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). 
Or you could try to send the individual intArrays via the bundle and put them together in the receiving Activity.
Like this:

```
int[] intarray1 = new int[] {4,5,6,7,8};
int[] intarray2 = new int[] {4,5,6,7,8};
int[] intarray3 = new int[] {4,5,6,7,8};

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putIntArray("INT_ARRAY1", intarray1);
bundle.putIntArray("INT_ARRAY2", intarray2);
bundle.putIntArray("INT_ARRAY3", intarray3);

Intent intent = new Intent(this,NewActivity.class)
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent)
```

Then in `NewActivity.java` you should create an array and get the bundle and fill the array with the received arrays.

Comment: that's not the problem you could do that dynamically but is this the result you want? send your individual arrays and put them in an ArrayList at the other Activity

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the Array List of integers by using the method `putIntegerArrayList`

Here is the code snippet

```
 ArrayList<Integer> values=new ArrayList<>();
            values.add(1);
            values.add(60);
            values.add(75);
            values.add(120);
 Bundle extras = new Bundle();
 extras.putIntegerArrayList(EXTRA_KEY,values);
```